# Reload a page once on start for IE9 users with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like a page to force reload once for IE9 users to clear the cache. I've been experimenting with this function:

```
location.reload();
```

The question: is it possibly to target people using IE9 and only reload ONCE on load.

Thankful for any help I can get.

/Linus

Comment: why do you want to reload it once only for IE users and how do you want to reload on click or on load and when you press F5 you dont want to reload on IE 9 ?!

Comment: I wan to reload the page once to delete the cache problem for the IE9 users. I would like to avoid a button and just make it work in the background. If possible that is.

Comment: when do you want to relaod page when you first go to page

Comment: I want the page to reload as fast a possible, directly after the page is loaded in the web browser, but only once.

Comment: if you found a way better of the answers let us know so every one can get help of this question

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best if you could devise some strategy which allows you NOT to depend on the browser version.

Having said that, here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will allow you to detect IE9.

Comment: Of course, but in this particular case I have no control over this. We are using Adobe Captivate wich results in that IE 9 users needs to clear cache do get a correct result in the LMS. I'm look for a way so the IE 9 users does'nt need to this manually.

Comment: @LinusJosephson: Ok, then you can check the link I have provided with the answer. It shows two simple functions which will tell you how to detect current IE version. You can also use Conditional Comments for this purpose.

Comment: That part I understand, thank you! But I don't se the solution to just reload the page just once!

Answer (score 0):

reference : [stackoverflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051413/redirect-to-html-page-using-javascript/11051521#comment14491837_11051521)

from the link to answer taken

Two options:

> 1- You can use cookies. Set a cookie when logging in and check for
>   that during load. Then clear it after performing your initialization
>   so that next load the check will fail.
>
> 2- You can use the address, either as a parameter like ?justLoggedIn,
>   or a value in the hash after #justLoggedIn. Then check for that and
>   redirect to the same url minus the justLoggedIn part. The advantage of
>   the # version is that it doesn't actually reload the page, unlike when
>   using the ? version.

**UPDATE**:
reference :[stackoverflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985507/one-time-page-refresh-after-first-load)

I'd say use hash, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

i think you should take a look at this question
i dont know about pjax until now so i dont know alot about it

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985507/one-time-page-refresh-after-first-load)

look at http://pjax.heroku.com/in the answers

Comment: Problem with the second option: In the '?' version, you cannot use `location.reload(true);` to force a fresh request. So the hash looks more promising here.

Comment: The page contains a Adobe Captivate webcourse inside a LMS, so I don't really have any freedom besides from editing the single HTML file with  inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS-code.

Comment: Window.location.hash doesnt work in the lms and generates a an unexpected alert when published. But it does work when I run it local.